# Javascript trouble when copying element from one array to another. Extra square brackets, extra dimensions?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Starting out with:

```
ArrayA = [    ["Element0"],  ["Element1"],  ["Element2"]    ];
```

and

```
ArrayB = [];
```

After a for-loop:

```
ArrayB[i] = ArrayA.splice(x,1);
```

then

```
ArrayB = [    [["Element0"]],  [["Element1"]],  [["Element2"]]    ]
```

Any clue WHY this is happening?

Comment: After *what* for loop? What are `i` and `x`? We can't possibly help you if you omit the code you're using to transform the first array into the second.

Comment: What did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: [Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) returns an array, so you're actually turning every element of ArrayA to a 1-length array

Comment: Why can't you just do var ArrayB = ArrayA.slice(0)?  Note the use of slice instead of splice.

Comment: I've done my best to explain this, but I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve. If you give a bit more context about what you're doing, people will be able to give more specific help.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Mike, not sure why it looked like that, it looked like your end edit on my screen BEFORE I hit submit, not sure how it collapsed.

Comment: @Meagar, The loop is a bit hard to show, it takes place over 4 different .js files. That is why I simplified it.  ArrayA is multidimensional AND HUGE, so I had to simplify it to be shown. It contains arrays of urls to be called, picture addresses, sound files, etc ALL associated with the topic of the array.   ArrayB is a temporary user-editable array, and B=A just allowed users to accidentally edit ArrayA when they changed ArrayB, hence the need for splicing. I thought it would JUST pull out a single element, instead of what Tim said.

Comment: @melpomene: ArrayA = [    ["Element0"],  ["Element1"],  ["Element2"]    ];    was supposed to Transfer ArrayB = [    ["Element0"],   ];        from: ArrayA = [    ["Element1"],  ["Element2"]    ];           instead of making: ArrayB = [    [["Element0"]],   ];          I had to address the old Array with  ArrayA[x][i],   and the new array had to be addressed with AbbayB[x][i][0].    My established system would NOT look for an extra dimension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array.splice returns an array of the removed items. In `ArrayA`, each item is an array, so Array.splice returns an array containing that array. For example,
`ArrayA.splice(0, 1)` returns `[["Element0"]]`. If you use a look to populate `ArrayB` like this, you'll end up with an array in which each element is an array containing a single array, which is what you have.

If you always use Array.splice for a single element and you want that element to be returned, you could write `ArrayA.splice(0, 1)[0]` to get the first element.

Also, do you really want `ArrayA` to be an array of arrays? Or do you want it to be an array of strings? If so, that would simply be `ArrayA = ["Element0", "Element1", "Element2"];` and the result of `ArrayA.splice(0, 1)` would be `"Element0"`.

Comment: It has been multi-dimensional, the new splice feature has just been adding errors (in the form of an extra dimension) to the existing structure I have been using for more than a year now.